# Clientside validation of UserControl with several DropDownLists

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, customvalidator

[SOLVED] Use WebControl (in this case Panel) to render a DOM-Element with the ClientID as id-attribute, that can be validated.

---

Didn't find any question/answer to this issue.

I got a UserControl with several DropDownLists (one CheckBox in all of those lists must be checked to get a true validation). 
Serverside validation works fine. Clientside validation not.
The OnClickEvent on any of the CheckBoxes doesn't trigger the Javascript code. Also the Sendbutton-Click doesn't trigger the validation for this UserControl.

Is there a way to tell the UserControl to trigger the validation javascript, if any of the Checkboxes in the UserControl gets clicked ?

(btw.: If u use a CustomValidator on CheckBoxLists, it automatically calls the javascript on click on its CheckBoxes, so I think the only Problem is, that i use a Custom UserControl that gets validated by a CustomValidator, so the CustomValidator doesn't get it, that the UserControl has Elements with OnClick-Events)

Comment: SOLVED: Found out UserControl renders no HTML Tag, switched to WebControl (especially: Panel). Renders a div with a ClientID. Clientside Validation now works.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Use WebControl (in this case Panel) to render a DOM-Element with the ClientID as id-attribute, that can be validated.